# How to update fragments dynamically?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs, android-tablayout

I am using Tab layout with view pager and adding fragments dynamically. Now I need to update a `TextView` which present in `ViewPager`s fragment,  according to swipe of fragment or click of tab. Suppose if I click on first tab or swipe my fragments  then `TextView` in `OperatorPlanList` fragment is updtate with text like "I just click". 
Note - TextView is present in layout of fragment.

When I try to find position by using `position` in get view method, `FragmentStatePageAdapter`, then I found out it update position twice when first or last fragment is seen.

So how can I update my fragment dynamically according to current fragment seen on screen in `ViewPager`???

This is my `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` adapter.

```
class ViewPagerFinder extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerFinder(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);

        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position){
            return  mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            System.out.println("getcount>>>" + mFragmentList.size());
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        }

        @Override
        public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
        }


        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }

    }
```

This is how I am setting up `ViewPager`.

```
 private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
            adapter = new ViewPagerFinder(getSupportFragmentManager());
            for(int i = 0; i<numberOfPlans;i++){
                adapter.addFragment(new OperatorPlanList(),"Plan");

//This is how I am setting up my fragments.

                viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

        }
```

This is how I am setting up my `Tab`s.

```
 private void setupTabIcons() {
        System.out.println("number of plans ="+numberOfPlans);
        for(int i = 0; i<numberOfPlans;i++){
            HashMap<String,String> map = applist.get(i);
            String planName = map.get("plan_name");
            TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
            tabOne.setText(planName);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(tabOne);

        }
    }
```

This is how I am calling my methods.

```
viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                    setupViewPager(viewPager);

                    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
                    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

                    setupTabIcons();
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface that all of the tab fragments will implement

```
public interface TabFragment {
    void onTabSwiped(int position);
}
```

In the class that hosts the ViewPager have it implement [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html)

Inside your ViewPagerFinder, during the instantiateItem() keep a list of TabFragment's (Create the fragment and cast it to the new interface, THEN call super).

Now in your Class that implements OnPageChangeListener, call the method onTabSwiped on all of your TabFragments passing in the position inside the overridden method onPageSelected(int position).

Now you will get a callback to each fragment during swiping, so you can check if its the correct position and perform whatever you need to do if it is the correct page.

There are ways to make this more efficient, but it's just a quick way to get it working. It will all be similar

-- You could also just get the fragment from your list inside your adapter during onPageSelected(int position), then call the interface method.

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position){
    pagerAdapter.mFragmentList.get(position).onTabSwiped();
}
```